# python code to convert excel1 format to excel2 format. Attaching the excel1 and excel 2 format

Tags: python, excel

python code to convert excel1 format to excel2 format. Attaching the excel1 and excel 2 format

[Excel1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf70T.png)
[Excel2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4BMJ.png)

I have tried program to extract the first cell and then iterate, but could not get logic.

Comment: Please see [ask], then [edit] your question and add the Python code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Rows("2:2").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("A2:B1048576").Select
Selection.Cut Destination:=Range("C2:D1048576")
Range("C1:D1").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A18"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A1:A18").Select
Range("A2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
Range("A3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A2:A18").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
Range("A1:A2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A18"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A1:A18").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[2]="""","""",R1C1)"
Range("A2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A2:A18").Select
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "DATE"
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "INTERVAL"
Range("C1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "FORCAST_COL"
Range("C2").Select
```